# Subset a data frame by a function that selects a dataset and a column for subset

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset

I have created a function which objective is to select between different data frames and subset the selected data frame from a selected column in that data frame:

```
#Dataset 1
cases <- c(1:10)
op1 <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
op2 <-  c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Dataset1 <- data.frame(cases,option1= op1,option2= op2)

#Dataset 2
cases <- c(1:10)
op3 <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
op4 <-  c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Dataset2 <- data.frame(cases,option1=op3 ,option2= op4)

# The function 
Data <- function( selection, dataset){
    Dataset1 <- with( dataset,  dataset [selection == 1,])
    Dataset1
}

# example of intended use
Data(selection= option1, dataset= Dataset2)
```

This creates an error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset, selection == "1", ) : 
  object 'option1' not found
Called from: (function () 
{
    .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
})()
```

But if I use it "manually" it works:

```
with( Dataset2,  Dataset2 [option1 == 1,])
  cases option1 option2
1     1       1       1
3     3       1       1
4     4       1       0
5     5       1       0
6     6       1       0
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong when creating the function?
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function `f` with an argument `x`, `R` wants to pass an object to the function. Writing `f(x)` makes `R` look for an object `x` in the workspace. In your case, `x` is not defined. `x` is hiding in another object called `Dataset1`. `R` can't find `x` there, so it tells you that `object option1 not found`. The object `op1` however is defined in the workspace. Telling `R` where to look for `x` is also an option, which is why passing `Dataset1$option1` would work. Similarly, you can pass objects directly, as in the case of a character "option1".

To exemplify:

```
Data <- function( selection, dataset){ # this is your function
  Dataset1 <- with( dataset,  dataset [selection == 1,])
  Dataset1
}
```

Using the object `op1` which is defined in the workspace:

```
Data(selection= op1, dataset= Dataset2)
  cases option1 option2
1     1       1       1
3     3       1       1
4     4       1       0
5     5       1       0
6     6       1       0
```

Telling `R` where to look:

```
Data(selection= Dataset1$option1, dataset= Dataset2)
  cases option1 option2
1     1       1       1
3     3       1       1
4     4       1       0
5     5       1       0
6     6       1       0
```

Or passing the name of the selecting column as a character vector to `R`. This requires some adjustment of the function:

```
Data <- function(selector, dataset){
  Dataset1 <- dataset[dataset[,selector] == 1,]
  Dataset1
}
Data(selector="option1", dataset= Dataset2)
  cases option1 option2
1     1       1       1
3     3       1       1
4     4       1       0
5     5       1       0
6     6       1       0
```

The reason why it works "manually" is that you use the `with(Dataset, ...)` wrapper, so that `R` looks in the column names of `Dataset` for a variable named `option1`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! if I change it in the function it does not work: Data <- function( selection, dataset){
    Dataset1 <- with( dataset,  dataset [Dataset$selection == 1,])
    Dataset1
}

Data(selection= option1, dataset= Dataset2) Do you know what I am still missing? It would be great that the selection is inside the function and not as a variable of the function

Comment: Don't change the function, change the function call, i.e. the argument that you are providing when you call the function.

Comment: That complicate a lot the usability of the function because I am planning to pass many datasets and many column names in a big dataset, to obtain different sub-datasets. Do you have any more ideas of how to solve this? (once again thanks!)

Comment: @YDO I have provided an example on how to do that in my edit.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am not getting your point or I am still missing some basic understanding of how it works . When you use op1 aren't you using  the vector for the filter, instead of the column in the dataset (that is what I would like to achive) (Thanks for the edit!)

Comment: When you call a function `f` with an argument `x`, `R` wants to pass an object to the function. Writing `f(x)` makes `R` look for an object `x` in the workspace. In your case, `x` is not defined. `x` is hiding in another object called `Dataset1`. `R` can't find `x` there, so it tells you that `object option1 not found`. The object `op1` however is defined in the workspace. Telling `R` where to look for `x` is also an option, which is why passing `Dataset1$option1` works. Similarly, you can pass objects directly, as in the case of the character "option1".

Comment: Now I understand what I was doing wrong with my function, thanks a lot! I will try to work around the issue